# Background image not displaying in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

A background image is not displaying in Chrome or Firefox. However, the image appears fine using other browsers.

- Relative and hard links
- Substitutions (and using an image file will work, video vanishes)
- Adblock not related

Apache shared server/shared hosting environment.

Expected result: background video playing at the top of the page. 
The background video is working on main landing page, but not on the section page... which is currently set up in .css (similar to the full-screen video background CSS method).

```
 <header id="header">
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <h1><span class="name">TEXT</span></h1>
            <h2><span class="someClass"><span>Design &#38; TEXT</span></h2>
            <p><a title="TEXT" href="TEXT" class="btn btn-default btn-lg page-scroll" class="class2"><i class="fa fa-level-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a title="TEXT" href="TEXT" class="btn btn-default btn-lg page-scroll" class="class22"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a title="Send email" href="mailto:TEXT?subject=EMAIL ADDRESS NEEDS EDITING&body=Please remove the text 'NOTSPAM' from the address before sending your email." class="btn btn-default btn-lg page-scroll" class="class22"> <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: .intro {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 100px 0;
 text-align: center; /*title block*/
 color: #fff;
 background: url(../../img/video.mp4) no-repeat center center ;
 background-color: #92b1ce;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
}

Comment: CSS background and background-image properties only accept colours, gradients, bitmaps and SVG as values.

Comment: To answer MarkMoxx: 
It is working as expected otherwise. 
This is a non-developer here hacking through this.

Comment: What do you mean it's working as expected otherwise?

Comment: To answer MarkMoxx: 
It is working as expected otherwise. 
This is a non-developer here hacking through this.
----
Several articles on using background movies that goto .css to employ.
Any other ideas to achieve the same result? Just Chrome and FF it seems having trouble with it.

Comment: Safari, Opera - mobile Safari, opera, chrome, firefox  - background video is working fine.

Comment: do you have a link to one of the articles you mention?

Answer (score 0):

You say background image is not showing, but then you say the background video is not playing. It seems you're trying to use an mp4 in your CSS background property - this will not work, the `background` property (or `background-image`, to be more precise - you're using the shorthand) does not support videos.

Comment: I am not a coder, and lucked out when the video itself played as hoped across most browsers including iOS (where I expected any trouble to be w/iOS background video autoplaying).

So it all works, except. Chrome and Firefox for desktop. Chrome and Firefox for iOS are even playing the video great.

While CSS background property is not meant to play video, it is and it is doing it well.. the glitch is Chrome and Firefox for desktop. 

http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video
https://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a video as background you need to think of layering two elements using index, position, and opacity. The first element is going to be the Video and on top of it the other element with Opacity. Take this link from W3schools as inspiration for the solution: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Comment: .           

Thought:
Could we simply target a static image just for the desktop versions of Chrome and Firefox... use the poster image so-to-speak?

----
Yes, the link for W3 was used for similar effort on the main landing page and works great including Chrome and Firefox for desktop. The second instance where this is needed, though, is a bit different...it is actually the same video mind you..page 1 is fullscreen. Page 2 is the same video, yet only taking up a small portion of the top of the screen. If you DM or email I will show you the two instances and maybe you'd have an idea.

Comment: I am getting some success taking that method and injecting into this other page (though it throws off the design elements as there is .css to iron out). In other words, as proof of concept I think this works on the second page as well.